# Shared libraries for GCC installed via yum on Fedora 20

Tags: yum, gcc, dynamic-linking

Unintentionally I erased my system `gcc` with a manually built one. To get things back, I did `yum reinstall gcc` and `gcc --version` attested that the initial version was back:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)
...
```

However, when I try to compile code I get the following error:

```
g++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
```

I looked at `/usr/lib64` and `/usr/lib` and didn't found any symlink to `liblto_plugin.so`. I discovered that it was in `/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/liblto_plugin.so`.

Then I made several efforts to point the compiler to it:

1. `g++ hello.cpp -L/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/`
2. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
3. `cd /usr/lib64`

   `ln -s /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/liblto_plugin.so`

   `cd ~; g++ hello.cpp -L/usr/lib64/`
4. `ldcondig -n /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/`

None of that helped. The error still appears. What should I do?

Comment: `g++` is packed separately on Fedora, try a `yum reinstall  gcc-c++`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered installing a new system on a different HD (or within a VM) with the same packages you have right now on your Fedora 20 and then copying over from there your entire /var and /usr directories?